# Как правильно: «зарегистрированная» или «зарегистрированным»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование

Как правильно написать предложение?
Верным будет "зарегистрированная" или "зарегистрированным"?

*Наша система дистанционного обучения является лицензионным программным обеспечением, официально **зарегистрированная** в Министерстве Юстиции Республики Казахстан*.

Comment: Вряд ли система обучения может являться программным обеспечением. ПО может входить в состав системы обучения – это другое дело.

Answer (score 2):

А что регистрируется-то? Система или программное обеспечение?

Если предположить первое, то надо перенести определение в нужное место:

*Наша система дистанционного обучения, официально зарегистрированная в Министерстве юстиции Республики Казахстан, является лицензионным программным обеспечением.*

Смысл такой фразы, правда, остается неясным.

Ну а если регистрируется, как и положено, ПО, то, естественно, с ним и надо согласовывать.

***Наша система дистанционного обучения является лицензионным программным обеспечением, официально зарегистрированным в Министерстве юстиции Республики Казахстан***

Предлагаемый вариант ("юстиции" - со строчной) соответствует общим правилам использования заглавных букв в именованиях ведомств РФ 
https://www.profiz.ru/sr/7_2008/pravila_napisania_oficial/

Возможно, в Казахстане свои указания на этот счет, но вообще заглавная тут смотрится плохо.

Answer (score 1):

Наша система дистанционного обучения является лицензионным программным обеспечением **(каким**?), официально **зарегистрированным** в Министерстве Юстиции Республики Казахстан.

Причастие "зарегистрированный" относится к существительному "обеспечение" и согласуется с ним в роде, числе и падеже.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря о чём идёт речь. Если о программном обеспечении, то, конечно же, — "зарегистрированным". В другом случае, предложение будет звучать коряво, и поэтому следует его перестроить.